# How to set up firefox so that a new tab opens next to the currently open tab?

Tags: macos, firefox, firefox-extensions

Is there a way (either through add-ons or preference tinkering?) to set up Firefox 17.0.1 (for Mac OS X) to open up new tabs next to the tab I am currently browsing in as opposed to at the end of my (often long) sequence of tabs?

UPDATE: I've tried making sure that `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent` preference is set to `true`. It is, but tabs still open at the end of the line of tabs. I've also disabled all add-ons to make sure nothing was overriding this--- still no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I've figured out the issue thanks to [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/808388) site.

The config option `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent` only affects tabs opened by a link from the current tab (hence the "related").

It seems that in order to get around this default Firefox behavior an add-on like [Tab Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-control/) is needed.

Answer (score 4):

That should be the default behavior in newer versions of Firefox, but if it's not for some reason, try navigating to `about:config` and make sure the `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent` preference is set to `true`.

Comment: And if the preference is not being respected, setting it to **false**, then back to **true** before restarting Firefox should fix it!